# Convert GPS time in R

Tags: r, date, time, gps

Help needed here. I'm reading a GPS file in R:

```
myData<-read.csv("gpsfile",colClasses="character"
```

Which later I'm planning to subset by times of the day.
The file header has 2 separate 'date' fields (aside from other non-date types):

```
UTC DATE    | UTC TIME 
2011/12/08    11:38:07
```

I'd like to convert UTC.TIME to a manageable time/date format. I've tried this:

```
myData<-read.csv("gpsfile",colClasses="character"
gpstime <- as.POSIXct(myData$UTC.TIME, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

but once done the content of gpstime INCLUDES today's date, sort of this:

```
"2014-02-14 11:15:41 GMT"
```

The GMT is correct (it's my time zone), but the date is not.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please `dput(head(myData))`, though most likely you need to do something like `as.POSIXct(paste(myData$UTC.DATE, myData$UTC.TIME), format="%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S")` or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date file contains:

```
UTC DATE    | UTC TIME 
2011/12/08    11:38:07
2011/12/09    10:38:07
```

This code might work, although it does not include the time zone and seems overly complex:

```
setwd('c:/users/mmiller21/simple R programs')

my.data2 <- readLines("date.time.csv")
my.data3 <- strsplit(my.data2, split = "(?<=[ ])(?=[0-9])", perl = T)
my.data4 <- do.call(rbind, my.data3[])
my.data5 <- my.data4[-1,]

# returns string w/o leading or trailing whitespace

trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
my.data6 <- trim(my.data5)

colnames(my.data6) <- c('my.date', 'my.time')
my.data6 <- as.data.frame(my.data6)

my.data6$date.time <- paste(my.data6$my.date, my.data6$my.time)

my.data6$date.time2 <- as.POSIXlt(my.data6$date.time)
my.data6

     my.date  my.time           date.time          date.time2
1 2011/12/08 11:38:07 2011/12/08 11:38:07 2011-12-08 11:38:07
2 2011/12/09 10:38:07 2011/12/09 10:38:07 2011-12-09 10:38:07
```

If the contents of the data file are (there is no header and there actually are commas separating the columns):

```
2011/12/08,11:38:07
2011/12/09,10:38:07
```

the code is much simpler:

```
setwd('c:/users/mmiller21/simple R programs')

my.data <- read.csv("date.time2.csv", header = FALSE)
colnames(my.data) <- c('my.date', 'my.time')

my.data$date.time <- as.POSIXlt(paste(my.data$my.date, my.data$my.time))
my.data

     my.date  my.time           date.time
1 2011/12/08 11:38:07 2011-12-08 11:38:07
2 2011/12/09 10:38:07 2011-12-09 10:38:07
```

If neither of these works with your real data perhaps post the first three lines of the real data set so I can see the exact content.  Or post three lines of fake data in the exact format used with your real data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. i just found the answer Mon morning coming back to work. I'll try it straight away. Still I'm baffled something so 'usual' (reading time in a standard format) takes so many lines.... Maybe the standard way of solving this is simply combining date and time fields (UTC.DATE+UTC.TIME) and processing one fields, no idea really.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user3310782 Five of the lines here are used to deal with the presence of a `|` as a delimiter in the header combined with no delimiter in the data themselves.  The code could be simplified a fair bit if you manually remove the header.  But if you have a lot of files that could be cumbersome.  I could add code for the latter scenario.